# Scala pattern matching performance

Tags: performance, scala, pattern-matching

I encountered this problem while doing homework from coursera "scala specialization" (this is simplified version and doesn't contain any homework details, it's just array traversal)

```
val chars: Array[Char] = some array

def fun1(idx:Int):Int = {
    some code here (including the stop condition)

    val c = chars(idx)
    c match{
      case '(' => fun1(idx+1)
      case  _  => fun1(idx+1)
    }

}
```

This code is 4 times slower than

```
def fun2(idx: Int):Int = {
    some code here (including the stop condition)

    val c = chars(idx)
    (c == '(') match{
      case true => fun2(idx+1)
      case  _  => fun2(idx+1)
    }
}
```

All I am doing is changing the pattern matching
(I am running it using ScalMeter so I believe in the statistics).

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

I can only confirm that the first `match` is ~50% slower, not 4x (2.11.8). Anyway if you look at the bytecode you can find that the first `match` is translated to `tableswitch` instruction, which is normally used for Java `switch` statement with multiple choices and is basically a lookup goto, while the second one is translated to `if`. So the second `match` is simply:

```
if (c == '(') fun2(idx+1) else fun2(idx+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** the below is wrong (the majority of time in these tests was spent generating the data, so the difference in actual traversal times was not noticeable. Running this same benchmark with constant input shows ~125ms per 100 million entries for `case ')'` case vs. ~35ms for the other case.)

I am not seeing the difference you are describing. Not sure how ScalaMeter does it, but running it in repl (after letting "warm up" by running "dry" a few times), I get virtually the same performance:

```
def func(s: Seq[Char], idx: Int): String = 
  if(idx == s.length) "foo" else s(idx) match {
    case ')' => func(s, idx+1)
    case _ => func(s, idx+1)
  }

def func1(s: Seq[Char], idx: Int): String = 
  if(idx == s.length) "foo" else (s(idx) == '(') match {
    case true  => func(s, idx+1)
    case _ => func(s, idx+1)
  }

import scala.util.Random
def randy = Stream.continually(Random.nextPrintableChar)


def doit(n: Int)(f: (Seq[Char], Int) => String) = {
 val start = System.currentTimeMillis;       
 f(randy.take(n).toIndexedSeq, 0); 
 System.currentTimeMillis - start
}


scala> doit(1000000)(func)
res9: Long = 231

scala> doit(1000000)(func1)
res10: Long = 238

scala> doit(1000000)(func)
res11: Long = 234

scala> doit(1000000)(func1)
res12: Long = 201
```

Etc. As you can see, no sizable difference.

Comment: I would doubt that this is anything near valid benchmarking method. ScalaMeter does like couple dozens of warmups until results stabilize. You don't even test using the same data.

Comment: Yep, not the same data. But I am getting pretty close results between the runs. The stddev is extremely low, which suggests, that if I used the same data, I would not see much of a difference. 
As mentioned in the answer, I have done warm ups as well, so not sure what about this benchmark you find "invalid". I stand by my findings, and challenge you to disprove them conclusively (and reproducibly) if you can.

Comment: Borrowing your functions, here is the benchmark with scala meter: https://gist.github.com/lukaszwawrzyk/a2505d5b3083bb72de51b8445fbb9a76 Giving `char time: 13.172258374999998 ms` and `bool time: 4.739404575 ms`. It is done for arrays as in the question, if using an indexed seq results are indeed closer but not equal (95 seconds vs 80 seconds)

Comment: @ Łukasz you are right. Turns out, most of the time in my experiments was spent generating the data. Running it with constant array does indeed show ~4x difference in run times.